# SQLite update statement performed without error, but table row not updated?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I cant for the life of me see what it could be? Any Advice? Thanks

```
(void)setRegId: (NSInteger) _regId

{

NSInteger r_id = _regId;
NSInteger row = 1;

ret = sqlite3_open(dbName, &database);
if (ret != SQLITE_OK)
{
    printf("Error opening the db: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return;
}

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement = nil;
if (compiledStatement == nil) {
    const char *sql = "UPDATE RegDB Set id = ? Where rowindex = ?";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: failed to prepare compiledStatement with message '%s'.",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return;
    }
}

sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, r_id);
sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, row);

int success = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
if (success == SQLITE_ERROR){
    NSLog(@"Error: failed to update compiledStatement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

if(sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: failed to closed DB with message     '%s'.",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

        }
```

Comment: are you debugging in simulator or on a device, is it possible that you are saving the update, but then overwriting the .db file on the next build?

Comment: im on a device. I think this close to the problem because the same code works fine in a separate project. I am running the update method a number of times while the app is running on the device, When I read the contents of the database they are always the default values set in the Db. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you are both sending the correct update statement, and that you are correctly reading the result.

Try logging your final statement (or at least the variables `r_id` and `row`). Use sqlite3 or SQLiteManager with Firefox to check changes in the database.